# bash continue execution on command failure

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash

while :
do
    filenames=$(ls -rt *.log | tail -n 2)
    echo $filenames
    cat $filenames > jive_log.txt
    sleep 0.1
done
```

I am trying to read latest 2 files from a directory and join them using bash. 
However when no files are present in the current directory with an extension .log the command `ls -rt *.log` fails with `error "ls: cannot access *.log: No such file or directory"`. After the error it looks like the while loop does not execute.
AfterWhat do I do so that the infinite loop continues even if one command fails.

Comment: Ignore errors using `filenames=$(ls -rt *.log 2>/dev/null | tail -n 2)`

Comment: 1.) Use `find` instead of `ls`. 2.) Bash exits only if the [errexit](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) option `set -e` is used. 3.) Use `set -x` to debug your script.

Comment: I am using ls -rt so that I can get the 2 newest files. I suppose find does not support this. Also, tried the set +e, but still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but perhaps:

```
for (( ;; )); do
    while IFS= read -r FILE; do
        cat "$FILE"
    done < <(exec ls -rt1 *.log  | tail -n 2) >> jive_log.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

Note the `ls` option `-1` which prints out files line by line.

Anyhow you can join last two files to jive_log.txt with:

```
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    cat "$FILE"
done < <(exec ls -rt1 *.log  | tail -n 2) >> jive_log.txt
```

Another way is to save it to an array (e.g. with `readarray`) then pass the last 2 elements to cat.

```
readarray -t FILES < <(exec ls -rt1 *.log)
cat "${FILES[@]:(-2)}" > jive_log.txt  ## Or perhaps you mean to append it? (>>)
```

Comment: "done <(exec ls -rt1 *.txt | tail -n 2) >> jive_log.txt" throws error. syntax error near unexpected token `<(exec ls -rt *.log | tail -n 2)'

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add another `<`. Please see update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the output of `find`, you have to add a sort key at the beginning, which can be removed later on.

```
find . -name \*.log -printf '%T+\t%p\n' |
sort -r |
head -2 |
cut -f 2-
```

Using `head` instead of `tail` is a bit cheaper.